# How do I split pandas Dataframe at a specific index that satisfies condition.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import a csv file of chatlog and first split it by date and then split each day's chat into multiple chunks when the condition between two consecutive rows is satisfied.

Then I want to put all of these in a dictionary where key is a date and the value is a list of chunks of the date.

This is what I've done so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# import csv of chatlog
ktlk_csv = pd.read_csv(r'''C:\Users\Jaepil\PycharmProjects\test_pycharm/5years.csv''', encoding="utf-8")

df = pd.DataFrame(ktlk_csv)

# Date column is str type. Change it into timestamp so I can later calculate diff between two rows. 
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

# criteria to separate chunks. 
chunk_tolerance = 900 # chat stopped more than 900 seconds
chunk_min = 5 # chat less than 5 lines is not a chunk. 

# First split the entire chat by day and put it in a list. 
df_byDate = []
for group in df.groupby(lambda x: df["Date"][x].day):
    df_byDate.append(group)

df["time_diff"] = df["Date"].diff()
```

I was thinking something like (pseudo code)

```
chatChunks_byDate = {}

for table_by_day in df_byDate:
  list_of_chunks = table_by_day.split?(condition: table_by_day["time_diff"] <= 900(i.e, chunk_tolerance):)

  list_of_chunks = [ x for x in list_of_chunks if not len(x.index) < 5(i.e, chunk_min) ] 

  chatChunks_byDate[ (date of table_by_day) ] = list_of_chunks
```

so the result would look something like

> >
>   chatChunks_byDate = { "Dec 12": [list of chunks on that day], "Dec 14": [list of chunks on that day] ....}

I tried to print some of the things above to solve it on my own but:

```
print(df.columns)
```

> >
>     Index(['Date', 'User', 'Message', 'time_diff'], dtype='object')

I can see that 'time_diff' column is created successfully.

```
print(type(df_byDate[0]))
```

> >
>   class 'tuple'

But why is it tuple? I expected it to be a dataframe.

```
print(df_byDate[0])

>> 
(5,                    Date User                                   Message
0   2017-09-05 19:25:46  권문광                      권문광 invited 전은영 and.
1   2017-09-05 19:25:47  권문광                                   졸사찍자 졸사
2   2017-09-05 19:29:16  전은영                            ㅌㅌㅌㅌㅌㅌㅋㅋㅋ
.
.
.
```

What is that 5 at the [0] place of the tuple? [1] seems to be a Dataframe I was looking for, but what is a value at [0] for?

So many things are confusing me.

Comment: You defined df_byDate as a list in your code; what makes you think it's a dataframe?

Comment: @sharatpc df_byDate is a list that should contain dataframes as its items, which are instead tuples(that contain dataframes at [1]). Maybe .groupby behaves that way but still what are the values at [0] of tuples?)